# Is it possible to suffer from hyperthermia by spending too much of time in the hot springs?

Tags: human-biology

People may tend to spend time in a hot water spring. Is it possible to get hyperthermia (like a sun stroke) due to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You betcha!](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20457444)

> We report a case of acute hepatic failure combined with disseminated
>   intravascular coagulopathy, acute renal failure, and neurological
>   deficit caused by heat stroke after bathing in a hot spring.

Generically, the term you're looking for is non-exertional heat stroke.